# How to keep C struct references to a C# struct with Marshal or GCHandle?

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling

I found several questions on this topic but nothing, which fits my exact problem. I'm having structs in a C DLL, for example like this one here:

```
extern "C"
{
    struct CStruct
    {
        int alpha;
        double beta;
    };
}
```

`CSharpStruct` has the same structure as its C friend, like this:

```
public struct CSharpStruct 
{
    public int alpha;
    public double beta;
}
```

and want to deliver the data by reference to a c# program.
I created a method in the C DLL which is able to return
a pointer to the `struct` like this one here: (test data)

```
const EXPORT_API CStruct* GetStruct()
{
    CStruct1.alpha = 21;
    CStruct1.beta = 23.141;
    return &CStruct1;
}
```

and I am able to access the data in c# in this way:

```
[DllImport("ASimplePlugin")]
private static extern IntPtr GetStruct();

//...

IntPtr cStruct = GetStruct();
CSharpStruct test = (CSharpStruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(cStruct, typeof(CSharpStruct));
```

After that I can access the data from C, but `Marshal.PtrToStructure`
copies them from the `IntPtr` reference into the C# `struct` **by Value**.

What I want to achieve is to have **a direct reference** to the c values
in the c# `struct` so that changing it in c# changes the values in c.

How is this possible?

Comment: I think you want `HandleRef`, not `GCHandle`

Comment: You need to fix the bug in the C code first, always make sure to unit-test the heck out of code before you try to pinvoke it.  You've got an off-by-one bug, the string is missing the zero-terminator.  Next, you'll need to pain yourself for while, figuring out where the free() call is going to be located to release the memory again.  You'll need to either use CoTaskMemAlloc() so the pinvoke marshaller can do it, and not need IntPtr, or you need to expose another function from your C code, like "FreeStruct".  And do consider GetStruct(struct test* buffer) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Infos Hans but the problems in our string example have been clear, this was 2min test code, i removed them for clearance, where our main problem is here.

Comment: Try reading about [In] [Out] parameters. I don't really remember details but it might be the thing you need.